# Почему упал сайт? 500

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс, администрирование

Ребят, не очень шарю в администрировании, есть такая проблема: сайт выдаёт 500 ошибку, глянул логи там спамит вот такая ошибка:

> ri Apr 22 04:07:31.657989 2016] [:error] [pid 16512] [client
>   85.14.245.175:48527] PHP Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in
>   /var/www/maxkondaurov/data/www/maxkondaurov.ru/bitrix/modules/main/lib/db/mysqlcommonconnection.php
>   on line 2 [Fri Apr 22 04:07:33.244247 2016] [:error] [pid 16513]
>   [client 85.14.244.114:48794] PHP Fatal error: Namespace declaration
>   statement has to be the very first statement in the script in
>   /var/www/maxkondaurov/data/www/maxkondaurov.ru/bitrix/modules/main/lib/db/mysqlcommonconnection.php
>   on line 2

Зашел в этот файлик на второй строчке там
**namespace Bitrix\Main\DB;**

В чем может быть проблема? это же стандартный файл битрикса, при чем сайт работал, но что то произошло и стала 500 ошибка вылетать, могу кинуть полный код файла mysqlcommonconnection.php

вот начало кода,в 3 строке убрал пробел, не помогло

```
<?php
namespace Bitrix\Main\DB;
use Bitrix\Main\ArgumentException;
use Bitrix\Main\Entity;

abstract class MysqlCommonConnection extends Connection
{
protected $engine = "";

/**
 * $configuration may contain following keys:
 * <ul>
 * <li>host
 * <li>database
 * <li>login
 * <li>password
 * <li>initCommand
 * <li>options
 * <li>engine
 * </ul>
 *
 * @param array $configuration Array of Name => Value pairs.
 */
public function __construct(array $configuration)
{
    parent::__construct($configuration);
    $this->engine = isset($configuration['engine']) ? $configuration['engine'] : "";
}

/**
 * Checks if a table exists.
 *
 * @param string $tableName The table name.
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isTableExists($tableName)
{
    $tableName = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9%_]+/i", "", $tableName);
    $tableName = trim($tableName);

    if (strlen($tableName) <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    $result = $this->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$this->getSqlHelper()->forSql($tableName)."'");

    return (bool) $result->fetch();
}

/**
 * Checks if an index exists.
 * Actual columns in the index may differ from requested.
 * $columns may present an "prefix" of actual index columns.
 *
 * @param string $tableName A table name.
 * @param array  $columns An array of columns in the index.
 *
 * @return boolean
 * @throws \Bitrix\Main\Db\SqlQueryException
 */
public function isIndexExists($tableName, array $columns)
{
    return $this->getIndexName($tableName, $columns) !== null;
}

/**
 * Returns the name of an index.
 *
 * @param string $tableName A table name.
 * @param array $columns An array of columns in the index.
 * @param bool $strict The flag indicating that the columns in the index must exactly match the columns in the $arColumns parameter.
 *
 * @return string|null Name of the index or null if the index doesn't exist.
 * @throws \Bitrix\Main\Db\SqlQueryException
 */
public function getIndexName($tableName, array $columns, $strict = false)
{
    if (!is_array($columns) || count($columns) <= 0)
        return null;

    $tableName = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_]+/i", "", $tableName);
    $tableName = trim($tableName);

    $rs = $this->query("SHOW INDEX FROM `".$this->getSqlHelper()->forSql($tableName)."`");
    if (!$rs)
        return null;

    $indexes = array();
    while ($ar = $rs->fetch())
    {
        $indexes[$ar["Key_name"]][$ar["Seq_in_index"] - 1] = $ar["Column_name"];
    }

    $columnsList = implode(",", $columns);
    foreach ($indexes as $indexName => $indexColumns)
    {
        ksort($indexColumns);
        $indexColumnList = implode(",", $indexColumns);
        if ($strict)
        {
            if ($indexColumnList === $columnsList)
                return $indexName;
        }
        else
        {
            if (substr($indexColumnList, 0, strlen($columnsList)) === $columnsList)
                return $indexName;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Returns fields objects according to the columns of a table.
 * Table must exists.
 *
 * @param string $tableName The table name.
 *
 * @return Entity\ScalarField[] An array of objects with columns information.
 * @throws \Bitrix\Main\Db\SqlQueryException
 */
public function getTableFields($tableName)
{
    if (!isset($this->tableColumnsCache[$tableName]))
    {
        $this->connectInternal();

        $query = $this->queryInternal("SELECT * FROM ".$this->getSqlHelper()->quote($tableName)." LIMIT 0");

        $result = $this->createResult($query);

        $this->tableColumnsCache[$tableName] = $result->getFields();
    }
    return $this->tableColumnsCache[$tableName];
}

/**
 * @param string $tableName Name of the new table.
 * @param \Bitrix\Main\Entity\ScalarField[] $fields Array with columns descriptions.
 * @param string[] $primary Array with primary key column names.
 * @param string[] $autoincrement Which columns will be auto incremented ones.
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Bitrix\Main\ArgumentException
 * @throws \Bitrix\Main\Db\SqlQueryException
 */
public function createTable($tableName, $fields, $primary = array(), $autoincrement = array())
{
    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE '.$this->getSqlHelper()->quote($tableName).' (';
    $sqlFields = array();

    foreach ($fields as $columnName => $field)
    {
        if (!($field instanceof Entity\ScalarField))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(sprintf(
                'Field `%s` should be an Entity\ScalarField instance', $columnName
            ));
        }

        $sqlFields[] = $this->getSqlHelper()->quote($columnName)
            . ' ' . $this->getSqlHelper()->getColumnTypeByField($field)
            . ' NOT NULL' // null for oracle if is not primary
            . (in_array($columnName, $autoincrement, true) ? ' AUTO_INCREMENT' : '')
        ;
    }

    $sql .= join(', ', $sqlFields);

    if (!empty($primary))
    {
        foreach ($primary as &$primaryColumn)
        {
            $primaryColumn = $this->getSqlHelper()->quote($primaryColumn);
        }

        $sql .= ', PRIMARY KEY('.join(', ', $primary).')';
    }

    $sql .= ')';

    if ($this->engine)
    {
        $sql .= ' Engine='.$this->engine;
    }

    $this->query($sql);
}

/**
 * Creates index on column(s)
 * @api
 *
 * @param string          $tableName     Name of the table.
 * @param string          $indexName     Name of the new index.
 * @param string|string[] $columnNames   Name of the column or array of column names to be included into the index.
 * @param string[]        $columnLengths Array of column names and maximum length for them.
 *
 * @return Result
 * @throws \Bitrix\Main\Db\SqlQueryException
 */
public function createIndex($tableName, $indexName, $columnNames, $columnLengths = null)
{
    if (!is_array($columnNames))
    {
        $columnNames = array($columnNames);
    }

    $sqlHelper = $this->getSqlHelper();

    foreach ($columnNames as &$columnName)
    {
        if (is_array($columnLengths) && isset($columnLengths[$columnName]) && $columnLengths[$columnName] > 0)
        {
            $maxLength = intval($columnLengths[$columnName]);
        }
        else
        {
            $maxLength = 0;
        }

        $columnName = $sqlHelper->quote($columnName);
        if ($maxLength > 0)
        {
            $columnName .= '('.$maxLength.')';
        }
    }
    unset($columnName);

    $sql = 'CREATE INDEX '.$sqlHelper->quote($indexName).' ON '.$sqlHelper->quote($tableName).' ('.join(', ', $columnNames).')';

    return $this->query($sql);
}

/**
 * Renames the table. Renamed table must exists and new name must not be occupied by any database object.
 *
 * @param string $currentName Old name of the table.
 * @param string $newName New name of the table.
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Bitrix\Main\Db\SqlQueryException
 */
public function renameTable($currentName, $newName)
{
    $this->query('RENAME TABLE '.$this->getSqlHelper()->quote($currentName).' TO '.$this->getSqlHelper()->quote($newName));
}

/**
 * Drops the table.
 *
 * @param string $tableName Name of the table to be dropped.
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Bitrix\Main\Db\SqlQueryException
 */
public function dropTable($tableName)
{
    $this->query('DROP TABLE '.$this->getSqlHelper()->quote($tableName));
}

/*********************************************************
 * Transaction
 *********************************************************/

/**
 * Starts new database transaction.
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Bitrix\Main\Db\SqlQueryException
 */
public function startTransaction()
{
    $this->query("START TRANSACTION");
}

/**
 * Commits started database transaction.
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Bitrix\Main\Db\SqlQueryException
 */
public function commitTransaction()
{
    $this->query("COMMIT");
}

/**
 * Rollbacks started database transaction.
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Bitrix\Main\Db\SqlQueryException
 */
public function rollbackTransaction()
{
    $this->query("ROLLBACK");
}

/*********************************************************
 * Type, version, cache, etc.
 *********************************************************/

/**
 * Sets default storage engine for all consequent CREATE TABLE statements and all other relevant DDL.
 * Storage engine read from .settings.php file. It is 'engine' key of the 'default' from the 'connections'.
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Bitrix\Main\Db\SqlQueryException
 */
public function setStorageEngine()
{
    if ($this->engine)
    {
        $this->query("SET storage_engine = '".$this->engine."'");
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Если не затруднит, приведите первые 2-3 строчки кода. Перед оператором namespace нет никаких других PHP-выражений?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятнее всего дело в символах в начале файла. По нормальному, код должен начинаться с `<?` или `<?php`, думаю у вас перед этим какие-то лишние символы. Возможно он редактировался в каком-то редакторе и была поставлена кодировка utf-8, а должна быть utf-8 без BOM, так как это добавляет лишние символы в начало файла.

Comment: <?php
namespace Bitrix\Main\DB;
use Bitrix\Main\ArgumentException;
use Bitrix\Main\Entity;

abstract class MysqlCommonConnection extends Connection
{
 protected $engine = "";

Comment: @ЕгорТрегубенко Вы лучше это в вопрос добавьте, а не к чьему-то ответу

Comment: @alias Вообщем там походу и правда был пробел лишний, я туда сюда удалял, вообщем заработало ура) кодировку так и не понял именно этого файла надо было сделать? я редактировал через isp manager , там нету без ВОМ только обычный utf-8

Comment: я просто не совсем разобрался , тут на сайте, совсем недавно) всем спасибо!